# Signal feature identification

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, signal-processing

I'm am trying to identify phonemes in voices using a training database of known ones.

I'm wondering if there is a way of identifying common features within my training sample and using that to classify a new one.

It seems like there are two paths:

1. Give the process raw/normalised data and it will return similar ones
2. Extract certain metrics such as pitch, formants etc and compare to training set

My interest is the first!
Any recommendations on machine learning or regression methods/algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged Python, I highly recommend looking into [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/), an excellent Python library for Machine Learning. Their docs are very thorough, and should give you a good crash course in Machine Learning algorithms and implementation (including classification, regression, clustering, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Your points 1 and 2 are not very different: 1) is the end results of a classification problem 2) is the feature that you give for classification. What you need is a good classifier (SVM, decision trees, hierarchical classifiers etc.) and a good set of features (pitch, formants etc. that you mentioned).

Comment: But are there any methods for feature discovery using a group of normalised signals?

Comment: Very good question, if I may. You can do feature discovery two ways: 1) By trial and error: get/extract as many features as you can and by statistical significance see which features are actually useful, or 2) get a DeeP Neural Network based classifier set and give it the input of as many features as you can; tune the weights in different layer to perform indirect feature selection.